# How to run Python Flask app on domain name?

Tags: python, flask

I own a domain name, how can I get my flask app to run on it, using my public IP address (assigned to me by my internet provider)? I don't want it to run on localhost, or my private IPv4 address, I want it to run on my Public IP address. Thanks in advance.

If it helps, I am using Google Domains.

Do I need to add anything to my flask app?

I'm currently running it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  db.create_all()
  app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was this a public IP provided by your Internet provider?  Or is it a public IP provided by a web hosting company?  The two answers are different.

If it came from a web hosting company, then you need to upload your flask app to your account on their server.  Note, however, that most shared hosting companies will not let you run an app 24/7.  They want to support FastCGI servers that come and go.

If this was provided by your Internet provider, then you will need to provide and configure a server.  You will need to have your router redirect port 80 and 443 to that server.  You will then need to run your flask app on that server.  Make sure your server is secure, because public-facing IP address get hammered by scammers.

Comment: My public IP was assigned to me by my internet provider.

Comment: Ok, thanks, what do I need to add to my flask app?

Comment: Hey, how do I configure a server? I am running my flask app, isn't that a server? It runs on localhost:80 (localhost). But I want it to run on my public IP address instead.

Comment: I mean a server computer.  You need to have a separate computer running 24/7 to receive requests run your flask application.  Do you have a computer to act as the host for your app?

Comment: Yes, I am currently running my desktop as a server, but it runs on my private IP address, I don't want that. Basically only people using my network can use my site.

Comment: That's just a matter of configuring your router.  You need to do "port forwarding" so that requests for port 80 on the outside network get forwarded to port 80 on your desktop machine.

Comment: Ok, do you mind finding a tutorial on how to configure my router on youtube and sharing? It would be appreciated. Thank you so much, I'll accept the answer after that.

Comment: No, I'm not going to do that.  Every router is different.  You have to know which router your ISP gave you, and you'll have to know the admin username and password.  If your internal IPs are 192.168.0.xxx, then your router is probably at 192.168.0.1 .  You can bring that up in a browser and see what it says.

Comment: Yes, okay, I did that and I'm getting there... until then, I'm exploring other simpler options, such as PageKite (https://pagekite.net). Thanks.

Comment: My router is 192.168.2.1 by the way, i don't know what that means.

Comment: Did that bring up a config page?  What router model does it say?  Do you know the admin username and password?

Comment: It only asked for a password, let me attach a screenshot in my question.

Comment: Do you know what I should click here?

Comment: https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r29904896-Internet-how-to-port-forward-on-Bell-Home-Hub-2000

Comment: Hi it still didn't work, i'm attaching the screenshot of my port forwarding in the question too. thanks.

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you try accessing the page by your public IP?  Have you setup your domain name to point to your public IP?

Comment: No not yet, I'm trying to access the page using my public IP right now.

Comment: Should I try using my setting up my domain and pointing to my public IP first as well? Thanks.

Comment: So my site is up and running at 192.168.2.20:443 right now, and my router page says that it should also be up and running at 69.159.43.172, but it's not. I don't understand why.

Comment: You forwarded port 80.  Did you also forward port 443?

Comment: It looks like you got it to work.  I can reach your site at port 443.

Comment: No, I am not really good with these settings, can you please explain exactly where to put these numbers? Thanks.

Comment: So what do you need to type to reach my site?

Comment: http://69.159.43.172:443   Usually port 443 would be HTTPS, but you're not providing a secure connection.

Comment: for me, it says that it took too long to respond for some reason.

Comment: It's possible.  Some routers make a distinction between "packets from the inside" and "packets from the outside".

Comment: Could you please also check whether you can reach my site through http://app.kopichiki.com? Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232007/discussion-between-savir-singh-and-tim-roberts).